# Issue with Powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am trying to use Powermockito in my test cases to test a `void delete()`method inside of a legacy `public final ClassToTest` but its throwing this exception when I am calling `mockStatic` on `ClassToTest`

Here is the exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 

org/mockito/internal/creation/instance/InstantationException
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:121)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:69)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:46)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:71)
    at nl.naturalis.nba.etl.ClassToTestTest.testLogDuration(ClassToTestTest.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.InstantationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:202)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:89)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 37 more
```

My ivy.xml for dependencies looks like this:

```
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11"/>
<dependency org="org.mockito" name="mockito-all" rev="1.9.5"/>
<dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-module-junit4" rev="1.7.3"/>
<dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-api-mockito" rev="1.7.3"/>
<dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-core" rev="1.7.3"/>
```

Inside the test method i m using these annotation :

```
@RunWith( PowerMockRunner.class )
@PrepareForTest( ClassToTest.class )
@PowerMockIgnore( {"javax.management.*"})
```

I did a debug to find to find that it fails exactly at this point when it tries to load this class :

```
org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer
```

Is there is something I m missing in the dependencies? or something else i am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using version 1.7.1 like it is specified in https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-Maven ?

Comment: I just just now its the same error. I m using Ubuntu OS does it have something to do with that? I just saw someone having issues with Mockito in their ubuntu system.

Answer (score 2):

The `org/mockito/internal/creation/instance/InstantationException` class has been introduced in the 2.x version of Mockito and is not available in you 1.9.5 version.

Also based on the compatibility table, you should aim for Powermock 1.5.6 version as its the latest supporting the 1.9.5 Mockito. [supported versions](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions)

Comment: I did update my mockito version to 2.0.2-beta and this exception is gone but now get this error 017-12-08 11:43:36,192 main ERROR Could not reconfigure JMX java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"

Comment: you need to update to at least 2.8.0 in order to use the latest powermock libraries

Comment: sorry i meant i updated my ivy.xml to this    `<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.4"/>
  <dependency org="org.mockito" name="mockito-all" rev="2.0.2-beta"/>
  <dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-module-junit4" rev="1.7.1"/>
  <dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-api-mockito" rev="1.7.1"/>
  <dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-api-easymock" rev="1.7.1"/>
  <dependency org="org.powermock" name="powermock-core" rev="1.7.1"/>`. Can you let me know which particular dependency you are mean?

Comment: the funny thing is my junit test passes now but i still get this error in the end: `2017-12-08 11:53:39,897 pool-1-thread-1 ERROR Unable to unregister MBeans java.lang.LinkageError: javax/management/MBeanServer
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterAllMatching(Server.java:335)` even if i have this annotation in my class  `@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*") `

Comment: i would suggest using the mockito-core dependency instead of mockito-all

Comment: Maciej Kowalski thanks for you input , my issues are resolved now. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Mockito's 1.9.5 is a very old version. Can you try to change it with the latest stable- 1.10.19.

Answer (score 1):

try to use in intellij Idea dependency analyzer plugin and resolve conflicts, this is looks like a dependency conflict.
PS update mockito to the latest 2.* version, i did it without conflicts or problems and the new version is very good

Comment: I did update my mockito version to 2.0.2-beta and this exception is gone but now get this error :   ERROR Could not reconfigure JMX java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"

Comment: the latest version of mockito is 2.13.0
dont use beta/snapshot versions in you app, you may get a lot of problems in future
http://site.mockito.org/

Comment: Thanks Igor I have updated the version to the 2.13.0.